# Photon, how to sync image and text via PhotonView or RPC?

Tags: unity-game-engine, synchronization, multiplayer, photon

I have a TextField and I need it to be displayed for all the players, and there is also a field with non-static images that should also be synchronized. I read that this can be done through the RPS, but I did not find a clear guide specifically for my problem.

Comment: RPC is the easiest way to accomplish this.  For the text, simply make an RPC function that accepts a string.  For the image, make an RPC function that accepts some sort of identifier that you can use to look up the image.  Inside the RPC functions, you want to display the item locally using a reference to an Image component and TextField component respectively.

Comment: @hijinxbassist
<code>using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class Sync : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public PhotonView view;
    public Text textGame;
   

    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void ViewAll()
    {
        textGame.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        view.RPC("ViewAll", RpcTarget.All);
    }
} <code> like this?

Comment: Please edit your question with the specific details of your issue.  The code above does not do anything, so i doubt that is what you want.  Do not run the RPC in Update like that, there is no point to it and causes a lot of unnecessary network traffic.

Comment: public PhotonView view;
    public Text textGame;
    public Text copied;

    void Awake()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        
    }

    public void sync()
    {
        if (view.IsMine)
        {
            view.RPC("ViewAll", RpcTarget.All, textGame.text);
        }
         
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void ViewAll(Text tG)
    {
        tG.text = copied.text;
           
    } I did, but its not work. I need sync textField from lead to players

Comment: You cannot send a Text component, you can however send the string.  `ViewAll(string text) { localTextComponent.text = text; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the text can transmit a photon, but the image cannot, with the text you just create a function and throw a string or TEXT there, and you should also have a photon view on the object.

```
public PhotonView view;
public Text textGame;
public Text copied;

void Awake()
{
    view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    
}

public void sync()
{
  view.RPC("ViewAll", RpcTarget.All, textGame.text);   
}

[PunRPC]
public void ViewAll(string tg)
{
   copied.text = tg;

}[enter image description here][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8skzD.png
Image pass its coordinates through Photon Transform View